# Dereferencing a vector of references in Rust

Tags: rust

I have the following DFS implementation in Rust that has a type inconsistency error right now.

```rust
fn dfs<T: Hash + Eq>(
    initial_state: T,
    is_final: &dyn Fn(&T) -> bool,
    next_states: &dyn Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>,
) -> Vec<T> {

    let mut final_states = Vec::new();

    {
        let mut stack = Vec::new();
        let mut seen = HashSet::new();
        stack.push(&initial_state);
        seen.insert(&initial_state);

        while let Some(node) = stack.pop() {
            if is_final(node) {
                final_states.push(node);
            }

            for ns in next_states(node) {
                if !seen.contains(&ns) {
                    seen.insert(&ns);
                    stack.push(&ns);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    final_states
}
```

The compiler currently complains because `final_states` is of type `Vec<&T>` and not `Vec<T>`.
If I update the function signature to return `Vec<T>`, the compiler complains with an error `returns a value referencing data owned by the current function` and points to `stack.push(&ns);` and other lines with `stack` and `seen`.

Is there a way to update final_states of type `Vec<&T>` to `Vec<T>`?

If not, what is the method to resolve the problem?

Edit:
If Copy trait is added to T (which I prefer not to do unless it is really necessary), there is another compiler issue with `for ns next_states(node)` that says "borrowed value does not live long enough". `ns` does not live outside of the loop.

[Link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=897b31b681e58bfbd018a36acf847037)

Comment: Update: Looks like it works if every state is cloned before placed in vector/set. Will write this up.

Comment: Still looking for a memory-efficient solution to the problem

Comment: If the states have an *id* or some other unique property, that'd be the best option to store into the `seen` set instead of clones or references.

Comment: @kmdreko That's an interesting thought. In my use case, it does not, unfortunately. The state-space too large to be stored in a single integer variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension on your self-answer.

- You should use `Clone` instead of `Copy` because it is less restrictive. Many types are `Clone` but far fewer are `Copy`. This also exposes an additional copy being done via `final_states.push(node)` that isn't obvious without `.clone()`.
- You make a few unnecessary clones. The only `.clone()` calls that should be necessary should be when putting elements in the `seen` set, as otherwise the state can be *moved* into the `stack`. You can *move* states out of the `next_states` results by iterating over `nss` instead of `&nss`.
- Moving the `is_final` check after the `next_states` step allows `node` to be *moved* to `final_states` instead of cloned. Since it is no longer used and has already been moved out of `stack`.

The updated code:

```
fn dfs<T: Clone + Eq + Hash>(
    initial_state: T,
    is_final: &dyn Fn(&T) -> bool,
    next_states: &dyn Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>,
) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut final_states = Vec::new();
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    let mut seen = HashSet::new();
    seen.insert(initial_state.clone());
    stack.push(initial_state);

    while let Some(node) = stack.pop() {
        let nss = next_states(&node);
        for ns in nss {
            if !seen.contains(&ns) {
                seen.insert(ns.clone());
                stack.push(ns);
            }
        }
        
        if is_final(&node) {
            final_states.push(node);
        }
    }

    final_states
}
```

---

If cloning is unacceptable, you can have `seen` and `stack`/`final_states` *share* ownership by using `Rc`s. Though its a bit more work to pull out the final states into a `Vec<T>` at the end.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn dfs<T: Debug + Eq + Hash>(
    initial_state: T,
    is_final: &dyn Fn(&T) -> bool,
    next_states: &dyn Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>,
) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut final_states = Vec::new();
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    let mut seen = HashSet::new();
    
    let initial_state = Rc::new(initial_state);
    seen.insert(Rc::clone(&initial_state));
    stack.push(initial_state);

    while let Some(node) = stack.pop() {
        let nss = next_states(&node);
        for ns in nss {
            if !seen.contains(&ns) {
                let ns = Rc::new(ns);
                seen.insert(Rc::clone(&ns));
                stack.push(ns);
            }
        }
        
        if is_final(&node) {
            final_states.push(node);
        }
    }
    
    // Ensure stack and seen are dropped early so that
    // final_states has unique ownership.
    std::mem::drop(stack);
    std::mem::drop(seen);
    
    final_states
        .into_iter()
        .map(|state| Rc::try_unwrap(state).unwrap())
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your graph structure is interesting, because it seems like you are generating the neighbors for each node on demand via a call to `next_states`. This is why the compiler complains when you change the return type to return a vector of references, as you are returning references to something (the neighbors of every visited node) that was generated during the execution of this function and will be dropped after the function finishes executing.

The easiest solution in this case is to make `T` [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) or [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html). This way, you can push a clone/copy of `node` onto `final_states`, and the compiler should stop complaining. Given that `T` implements both `Hash` and `Eq`, I would guess that it is a good candidate to be `Clone`able (or `Copy`able) as well, as any reasonable implementation of `Hash` and `Eq` would ensure that `x.clone() == x` returns true.

Comment: Just curious if there exists a memory-efficient alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: Given how you are generating the neighboring states for every node, a different solution seems likely. It is important to note that `Copy`ing a value is usually very cheap, and this solution doesn't actually use more memory than needed (you will need to store the values returned somewhere, and all you have access to is references).

Comment: I don't buy the argument of "this solution doesn't actually use more memory than needed" as it has to copy the memory that's already allocated. However, I buy the other argument of "Copy"ing is usually very cheap. One caveat here is that `T` needs to be `Copy`able. Forcing a generic type to have a trait that theoretically does not require is not very generic.

Comment: In addition, this change failed to work. Still got a different compiler error.

Comment: If you've made `T` `Copy`, then just add `ns` itself rather than a reference to it to `seen` and `stack`. EDIT: This is exactly the same thing you mentioned in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the lifetimes of variables in the code. Specifically, states generated from `next_states`. There is a couple of issues associated with it.

1. Once the reference of the variable is moved, you cannot move the variable itself. For the case above, the variable `ns` is moved as a reference in `seen.insert(&ns)` and hence, it's not possible to return the variable outside of the function as `Vec<T>`.
2. The memory of the variable has a scope. The memory allocated within the loop at `next_states(node)` is deallocated when it goes outside of the scope. Hence, the states cannot be accessed outside of the loop.

One solution to the problem is to clone the memories when it needs to be moved so that it avoids memory ownership problem altogether. However, this is not the most memory-efficient way to solve the problem and T needs to implement additional trait `Copy`.

Here is the updated code.

```rust
fn dfs<T: Copy + Eq + Hash>(
    initial_state: T,
    is_final: &dyn Fn(&T) -> bool,
    next_states: &dyn Fn(&T) -> Vec<T>,
) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut final_states: Vec<T> = Vec::new();
    let mut stack = Vec::new();
    let mut seen = HashSet::new();
    stack.push(initial_state.clone());
    seen.insert(initial_state);

    while let Some(node) = stack.pop() {
        if is_final(&node) {
            final_states.push(node);
        }

        let nss = next_states(&node);
        for ns in &nss {
            if !seen.contains(&ns) {
                seen.insert(ns.clone());
                stack.push(ns.clone());
            }
        }
    }
    final_states
}
```

Comment: It looks like you can change `stack` to `Vec<&T>` and `seen` to `HashSet<&T>` and remove all the `.clone()`s except for the one when pushing to `final_states` (which, I imagine you want since you're returning the value and you want the values to be owned by the returned `Vec`). Basically the idea would be that, while doing the DFS, you don't need to _own_ values, you just need to be able to _look_ at them (so that you can find their neighbors).

Also it looks like you can change the `Copy` trait bound to `Clone`.

Comment: Oh, wait, sorry, that was all assuming `next_states` returned _references_ to `T`s. I was assuming that `next_states` returned references to neighbors of `node` instead of owned versions. If `next_states` returns _owned_ values, then `nss` dies after the `for` loop and `seen` can no longer hold onto those values (because they've been freed and are dangling). In that case, you'd have to clone (or move by changing `in &nss` to `in nss`) into the `HashSet` (as far as I know - I assume someone smart will show up and help!)